# Extracting element-name from xml input in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an XML input that looks like this:-

```
<root>
  <type>abc</type>
  <data>
    <attributes>
      <atr1>
        <values>val1</values>
      </atr1>
      <atr2>
        <values>val2</values>
      </atr2>
      . .
    </attributes>
  </data>
</root>
```

the attributes child node (atr1,atr2..or even xyz.) can be any value and hence want to extract the name of the child node dynamically and then output it as an xml element only.

my xslt right now looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <type>
        <xsl:value-of select="root/type" />
      </type>
      <Attributes>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/data/attributes">
          <Attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <values>
              <xsl:value-of select="attributes/values/value" />
            </values>
          </Attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Attributes>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

whats the right way to extract the element-name of 'attributes' child nodes?

i want my output xml structure to look like this:-

```
<root>
  <type />
  <attributes>
    <atr1><value /></atr1>
    <atr2><value /></atr2>
    . . .
  </attributes>
</root>
```

**Update**:
was asking to extract values since in the output i have to add this element as an attribute

```
<root>
  <type/>
  <attributes>
     <attribute param="atr1">
         <value/>
     </attribute>
     <attribute param="atr2">
         <value/>
     </attribute>
     ..
  </attributes>
<root>
```

Comment: Your "update" is an entirely different question.

Comment: I'm aware of that, just thought of continuing in the same thread, anyways I figured how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process all child elements with `*` (e.g. `root/data/attributes/*`) and then of course use `name()` or `local-name()` to read out the name of the currently processed child element.